# why am i not able to import google-cloud-speech?

Tags: pycharm, python-3.5, google-cloud-speech

I have instlled google SDK, which seems to responding fairly good. I have also downloaded google-cloud-speech for my speech to text conversion. however, when I try to import google.cloud, I do not see any suggestion for "cloud" in my IDE(Pycharm). i tried to reinstall the library by 2 ways, using PIP and another in Pycharm. None of them seems to be working. To verify I have checked the path for the installed library, and surprisingly they exist there. Below is the output from my CLI

```
root@amitesh-VirtualBox:/home/amitesh/PycharmProjects/streaming/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google# pwd
/home/amitesh/PycharmProjects/streaming/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google

root@amitesh-VirtualBox:/home/amitesh/PycharmProjects/streaming/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google# ll
total 48
drwxrwxr-x 12 amitesh amitesh 4096 Jun 19 11:41 ./
drwxrwxr-x 30 amitesh amitesh 4096 Jun 19 16:27 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 amitesh amitesh 4096 Jun 19 11:41 api/
drwxrwxr-x  6 amitesh amitesh 4096 Jun 19 11:41 api_core/
drwxrwxr-x  6 amitesh amitesh 4096 Jun 19 11:41 auth/
drwxrwxr-x  5 amitesh amitesh 4096 Jun 19 11:41 cloud/
```

NOTE:

1)I did go through the google-cloud-speech documents, and python3.5 is a supported version.

2) I have seen multiple article on stackoverflow, but none of them has the right guidance.

3) I have also used plain notepad to see if its working. But no.

My environment

```
python3.5
pycharm2018.1.2 community version
ubuntu 16.4
```

Comment: should just be `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech` and `from google.cloud import speech`

Comment: Did you try the above solution: "pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech and from google.cloud import speech" to see if it works for you?

Comment: The issue is resolved, thank you for your suggestio

Answer (score 0):

Solution: pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech and from google.cloud import speech